# python "websockets" and "asyncio" in Locust display "was never await"

Tags: python, websocket, locust

python code is following ，file name is my.py;

```
#!./venv/bin/python
# Author: Adam
# Data  : 2024-02-28

from locust import User, task, between, constant
import asyncio, websockets
import requests, time, struct, json,  random
from  my_stress_package import LogIn_pb2, MyEvent_pb2, MyQuest_pb2, Quote_pb2, UserInfo_pb2
from  my_stress_package.Mybase import log_writer

Logger = log_writer()

exception_status = {
    "8888": "Heartbeat", "8889": "Quotes", "8890": "Quotes Subscribe", "8885": "Disable Login",
    "8886": "Login Failed", "8887": "Muitple Login", "9998": "Market Closed", "9999": "Login Successed", "10000": "Login",
    "10001": "Products Search", "10002": "Products info", "10003": "Products Smary Search", "10004": "Products Smary Info",
    "10032": "Buy Successed", "10034": "Buy Limit successed", "l0036": "Sell successed", "10038": "Sell Limit successed"
    }


class MyLocustTrade(User):
    
    # INIT
    async def on_start(self):
        self.wscon = await websockets.connect("ws://192.168.130.100:9000/api/test/auth/websocks/my5SockBin", timeout=5)

    
    async def on_stop(self):
        if self.wscon:
            await self.wscon.close()
      
    # LOGIN_DATA TO BINARY PACKAGE
    def my_login_data(account, pwd, device):
        header_code = 10000
        int_part = struct.pack('!i', header_code)
        login_pb_data = LogIn_pb2.LogIn()
        login_pb_data.login = account
        login_pb_data.pwd = pwd
        login_pb_data.device = device
        pb_serialized_data = login_pb_data.SerializeToString()
        data = int_part + pb_serialized_data
        return data
      
    # TRADE_DATA TO BINARY PACKAGE
    def my_trade_data(data):
        header_code = 10031
        int_part = struct.pack('!i', header_code)
        trade_pb_data = MyQuest_pb2.NewOrder()
        trade_pb_data.sbl = data["sbl"]
        trade_pb_data.act= data["act"]
        trade_pb_data.type= data["type"]
        trade_pb_data.price= data["price"]
        trade_pb_data.vol= data["vol"]
        trade_pb_data.sl= data["sl"]
        trade_pb_data.tp= data["tp"]
        pb_serialized_data = trade_pb_data.SerializeToString()
        data = int_part + pb_serialized_data
        return data
    
    # TRADE_DATA SEND
    async def my_data_send(self, data):
        await self.wscon.send(data, timeout=5)
      
    # TRADE_DATA RECEIVE
    async def my_data_receive(self):
        data = await self.wscon.recv(timeout=5)
        login_rep_code = data[0:4]
        login_rep_data = data[4:]
        rep_code_str = struct.unpack('!i', login_rep_code)[0]
        return [rep_code_str, login_rep_data]

    wait_time = constant(300 )

    @task
    async def my_locust_task(self):
      # THIS IS A TRUE SINGLE DATA
      account = 3101
      pwd = "12345678"
      device = random.choice([1,2,3,4])
      buy_data_demo = {"sbl": "DOGEUSDT", "act": 200, "type": 0 ,"price": 0.5, "vol": 100, "sl": 0.01, "tp": 1.99}
      login_data = self.my_login_data(account, pwd, device)
      trade_data = self.my_trade_data(buy_data_demo)

      # HERE SEND LOGIN DATA AND RECEIVE 
      await self.my_data_send(login_data)
      recv_binary2str = await self.my_data_receive()

      # ACTUALLY THE RETURN DATA IS A LIST IT'S INCLUDE 2 ELEMENTS,THE PART-1 IS A INT-STATUS-CODE AND DATA IS PART-2;
      rep_code, rep_data = recv_binary2str

      if rep_code == 9999: 
          # HERE WE USE PROTO-BUFF-FILE PARSE THE PART-2 DATA
          userinfo_pb_data = UserInfo_pb2.UserInfo
          login_rep_data_str = userinfo_pb_data.ParseFromString(rep_data)
          print(login_rep_data_str)

          # SEND AND RECEIVE TRADE DATA
          self.my_data_send(trade_data)
          rep_code, rep_data = recv_binary2str
          # 
          if rep_code in [10032, 10034, 10036, 10038]:
              Quest_pb_data = MyQuest_pb2.Response
              rep_data_str  = Quest_pb_data.ParseFromString(rep_data)
              Logger.info(f"登录返回 {rep_data_str}")
              print(rep_data_str)
              return  rep_data_str
          else :
              status = exception_status[str(rep_code)]
              return {"status": status}
```

when i run "locust -f my.py --headless -u 1 -r 1 --run-time 5"

[image]

How can i fix it ?

My confusion:

0.  i used "websockets" and "asyncio" modules in Locust as loading test the websocket-api with python, am i use a wrong-solution ? if it is what is the better solution ?   if not go ahead the following.

1.  am i not clear to understand the   Locust-calss-usage ?

2.  am i not clear to understand the   websockests-usage ?

3. am i not clear to understand the   asyncio-usage  in python?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: sure i commit it again , thank you

Comment: Locust doesnt support asyncio, at least not out of the box. Check out locust-plugins’s SocketIOUser maybe.